# Hide root component html based on current active route

Tags: angular

Below image depicts my SPA developed using Angular 2.

[image]
The menu links shown in the top are part of root component , and below is the html of root component.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']" routerLinkActive="active" >eShop Admin</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ><a [routerLink]="['']">Home</a></li>      

      <li><a [routerLink]="['./categories']" routerLinkActive="active">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['./products']" routerLinkActive="active">Products</a></li>

      <li><a [routerLink]="['./about']" routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
      <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>      

  </div>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now my requirement is if the current active route is "Login" , then the menu links in the root component should not be displayed.

Any idea what is the best way to implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed below steps to hide/display links based on active route

1. Created a service(AppService) with a boolean property "blnDisplayMenu" set to true by default.

   ```
   import { Injectable , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   @Injectable()
   export class AppService implements OnInit {

      public blnDisplayMenu:boolean;

      constructor() { 
       this.blnDisplayMenu = true;
      }

      ngOnInit() { }
   }
   ```
2. And below is relevant root component ts code where based  on value of
   "blnDisplayMenu" , it is decided whether to display the menu or not.

   ```
    ...
   import { AppService } from './app.service';

   blnDisplayMenu:boolean;

   constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

   ngDoCheck() {        
   this.blnDisplayMenu = this.appService.blnDisplayMenu;        
   }
   ```
3. In the html of app root component , menu is displayed based on value of blnDisplayMenu

   ```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" *ngIf="blnDisplayMenu">
   ```
4. In login component value of  blnDisplayMenu property of AppService is to false in ngOnInit and to true in ngDestroy life cycle hooks.

Comment: This worked for me when I moved the setter of the AppService.blnDisplayMenu from ngOnInit() to constructor of the Component's constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to ActivatedRoute.url property (Observable) and use an asynchronous *ngIf on your `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`

Example:

```
class {
    isLoginPath$: Observable<Boolean> = this.route.url.map(url => url[0].path).map(path => path === 'login');

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
}
```

Then, in your html, you can have:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" *ngIf='!(isLoginPath$ | async)'>
```

With this method, you map the url observable inside the route, to an observable of true or false depending on the route you are. Because of the async pipe, it should automatically show or hide the elements depending on the last event emitted by the observable.

More info on the official docs about ActivatedRoute: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#activated-route

Comment: Updated answer with appropiate syntax for the observable. If it doesn't work , please provide me with more info, if it throws any error, or any info that could help.

Comment: I added console.log to check the value of 'path' and it is always null. ".map(path =>{ console.log('path' + path); return path === 'login'} );"

Comment: Can you provide the code of your component.ts and the code of the template you have modified? Also, editted 'isLoginPath$ | async' to '!(isLoginPath$ | async)'